# R: use mice mipo/data.frame object with sjPlot tab_model

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-mice, sjplot

I'm trying to get a table output for a pooled logistic model with imputed datasets from mice so I can see and report the standardized and exponentiated estimates and model fit statistics, but it seems like tab_model will not take a mipo/data.frame object that comes from analyzing pooled data.

Here is an example with the `trial` dataset from the `survival` package.

```
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)
library(sjPlot)

suppressWarnings(mice::mice(trial, m = 2)) %>%
        with(glm(death ~ marker + grade, family = "binomial")) %>% 
        pool() %>%
        tab_model(., show.se = TRUE, show.std = TRUE, show.aic = TRUE)
```

This give me this error:

```
Error in if (fam.info$is_linear) transform <- NULL else transform <- "exp" : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Is there a way to use pooled mice object with tab_model? Or convert it to a type of object tab_model will take?

Comment: I've encountered similar issues and so far I haven’t found a way to use mice objects with tab_model or tab_corr – maybe this is worth posting on https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot as a future enhancement?

Comment: Done! Good thought, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a `mice` issue, but a problem with `tab_model()` and `broom` objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70422199/17724015 and https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/385.