# R: APA regression tables with mipo/mice objects

Tags: r, dplyr, regression, r-mice, sjplot

I have historically used `sjPlot` to create APA-style regression tables that export directly as a `docx`. Unfortunately, models based on imputed data (`mipo` objects) are not currently compatible with `tab_model`.

I am looking for a function similar to `tab_model` that can export APA-style regression tables directly to a Word Document in a single chunk without having to knit. Most packages I found (e.g., `stargazer`) seem to require knitting to create the table. Alternatively, if anyone knows a workaround to get `mipo` objects to work with `tab_model`, I would be most appreciative.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sjPlot)
library(mice)
set.seed(123)

# error
data(nhanes)
imp <- mice(nhanes, m=3, print=FALSE)
with(imp, lm(age ~ bmi + chl)) %>% 
  pool() %>% 
  tab_model(.,
            file = "table.doc")
#> Error in fam.info$is_linear || identical(fam.info$link_function, "identity"): invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mice` relies on `broom::tidy()` and `broom::glance()` within the `pool()` function. So I think the solution may be found in the combination of `tab_model()` with a broom object, such as here: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/385.